# A partial differential equation- transport equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am a begining learner of pde. I am trying to solve the following the transport equation
$$u_t + [1- (t^2 - x^2)(2b + a x^2)]\frac t x u_x= -f u,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the differentiable functions of $t$.

**My solution:** 
$$\frac{dt}{1} = \frac{dx}{ [1- (t^2 - x^2)(2b + a x^2)]\frac t x } = \frac{du}{-fu}.$$
From $\frac{dt}{1} = \frac{dx}{ [1- (t^2 - x^2)(2b + a x^2)]\frac t x}$, we know that 
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{x^2 - t^2}) + \frac{2t(a t^2 + 2b)}{x^2 - t^2} = -2at.$$
This is a Bernoulli equation. One can easily get its solution

$$\frac{1}{x^2 - t^2} = \frac{c - \int 2at e^{\int 2t(a t^2 + 2b) dt} dt}{e^{\int 2t(a t^2 + 2b)dt}}.$$
Then
 $$c= \frac{(x^2 - t^2)\int 2at e^{\int 2t(a t^2 + 2b) dt} dt + e^{\int 2t(a t^2 + 2b) dt}}{x^2 - t^2}.$$
But i do not know how should continue it???
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Regards @user . I would like to know what is $dr$ and $ds$, and the initial condition ? Thanks

Comment: @user Why can you do step one of your solution?

Comment: @Arief sorry, i made the mistakes.it is corrected.

Comment: @user you have not yet answered my question - in the first line of your solution, what is your reasoning for this?

Comment: @unseen_rider : Obviously le first line of the solution is the correct set of characteristic ODE's for solving thanks to the method of characteristics.

Comment: @user : I have not enough time right now to check your calculus. Supposing that it is correct, you got a first characteristic equation $c_1=...=g(x,t)$ that you found. A  second characteristic equation is $c_2=e^{ft}u$. The general solution : $e^{ft}u=F(g(x,t))$ where $F$ is any differentiable function.